# Travelling to China, wondering what diseases/infections they are screening for?

Tags: health, china, airport-security, pvg

Last time I travelled to China (Shanghai, airport: PVG) there was some kind of imaging system that allegedly screened people entering for some list of diseases.

I have a cold or flu or some kind of upper respiratory infection right now. Primary symptom is an awful cough and phlegm (sorry to be descript)

I am wondering if I should expect any issue entering?

Comment: Was it the fever screening, begun because of SARS and Avian flu?

Comment: It may very well have been that. It was only last year I was there, so I would think they still have it.

Comment: It may resemble the security frame that stores have to prevent theft; walk through and infrared detects body temperature. Accuracy rates are under 70 percent but, if you were to be stopped, which is unlikely if you have a cold, it would be for additional screening.

Comment: Ok, I don't think I have a fever but I'll take some ibuprofen before we land in case. Thanks

Comment: Almost certainly just fever. During the SARS outbreak in Toronto they installed these. Several infected people arrived without detection; lots of uninfected people were delayed and made to feel worse. But I guess installing these feels like "doing something" so it still happens. Try not to have a fever in an airport if you can possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These devices are infrared thermometers used to screen people to check if they have a fever. If one has a fever, he/she will be required to have his/her body temperature taken, and will potentially be sent to medical facilities if there is something wrong.

There was a few avian and swine influenza epidemics in China a few years ago (and also the infamous SARS epidemic) which went pretty bad, so border authorities decided to sceeen people and check if they have suspicious fevers.

If you don't have a fever, you will pass without questions asked. If it's a very slight fever (i.e., <37.5 degrees Celsius), I don't think there will be problems either - just take good rest.